# SharePoint master page problem

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm modifying "Randy Drisgill" blank master page template( publishing ) . I've added a combo box like,
[image]

When I preview on web , everything looks fine as below,

[image]

But I noticed upload document form is getting the same combo box header ,

[image]

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you add the section of the code where you made the change?  It sounds like you need to move it from an area of the main content into an area for the header.  But it's hard to know for sure without the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the controls you added for your Dapertments dropdown is in a div tag, and add class="s4-notdlg" to it. This will prevent your dropdown from appearing in SharePoint's modal dialog.

For example:

```
<div class="s4-notdlg">
  <span>Departments</span>
  <span>{...code for your dropdown control...}</span>
</div>
```